# How can I use django-storages for both media and static files?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm attempting to use http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html for serving **both** static files **and** uploaded media, but I'm not certain it's possible. Is there a documented way that I'm missing? Also, I would assume (hope) that you could configure a separate bucket for each, but I can't find any info on that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is possible by configuring both `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to use the S3 storage. However if you set

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

then these will both use the default settings for the S3 storage, meaning they will both use the `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` bucket. The way to work around this is to create a small subclass of `S3BotoStorage` in your project which uses a different setting for the bucket name.

```
from django.conf import settings

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket']  = settings.AWS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME
        super(S3StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You would then define the `AWS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME` setting to be whatever you want for your static bucket and change `AWS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME` to the path for this custom storage class.

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'dotted.path.to.storage.S3StaticStorage'
```

If you wanted to change other settings such as `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH`, `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`, `AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA`, etc then you would change them in this subclass as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark. What I ended up doing before coming back to your more extensible solution was to subclass the storage, but override the `bucket_name` attribute on the class as `bucket_name = setting('S3_STATIC_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')`.

Comment: Yep that's the same basic idea. Both address the main problem which is the storage used by `STATICFILES_STORAGE` will be initialized with the default args, kwargs so you need to make sure those defaults are what you want.